# Is there a way to access the WebRequest in a c# wcf client?

Tags: c#, wcf

Is there a way to access the `WebRequest` object used for the invocation of a remote method in a generated c# wcf client? Perhaps through the binding (e.g. `BasicHttpBinding`)?

Thanks Beforehand!

Comment: Is your client consuming an existing third party web service or your own?

Comment: It is my own web service, but written in Java and deployed remotely. So like a third party service. And the reason why I would like to access the WebRequest is that I can better take care of the authentication against a network proxy inbetween. Why are you asking?